# How to set vue-cookie expiry in hours

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have below code to expiry my vue-cookie in 3 hrs

```
VueCookie.set('S3ID', getS3ID, 3);
```

This function is setting cookie expiry time as 3 days instead of 3 hrs. Is there any reason to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
VueCookie.set('S3ID', getS3ID, '3h');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Date object:

```
var expireIn = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 180 * 60 * 1000);
VueCookie.set('S3ID', getS3ID, {
    expires: expireIn
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

```
VueCookie.set('S3ID', getS3ID, { expires: "3h" });
```